# Как только 1 сайт пустить через VPN?

Tags: ubuntu, маршрутизация, vpn

Вопрос по VPN и роутингам в Ubuntu 22

Как только 1 сайт пустить через VPN?

Comment: да как обычно: `$ sudo ip route add ip.адрес via шлюз dev интерфейс`